Optimal strategy/win probability for sequential uniform random variable comparisons
Suppose you are sequentially presented with $n$ random variables, $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$, which are all drawn from U(0,1). After being presented with each variable, $x_i$, you must declare where the number would sit on an ordered list of all $x_1$ to $x_n$ (ie. largest, second largest, smallest, etc.). What is your optimal strategy for declaring the relative positions and what is the probability of success (no incorrect answers across all $x_i$).
For $n=3$, I think the algorithm should be as follows

$x_1$

max if $x_1 > 2/3$
min if $x_1 < 1/3$
mid if $1/3 < x_1 < 2/3$


$x_2$

if $x_1$ was max

if $x_2 > x_1$, $x_2$ is max (and we lose game)
if $x_2 < 0.5$, $x_2$ is min
if $0.5 < x_2 < x_1$, $x_2$ is mid


if $x_1$ was min, we operate similarly to if $x_1$ was max
if $x_1$ was mid

if $x_1 < x_2 < 0.5$ or $0.5 < x_2 < x_1$, $x_2$ is mid (and we lose)
if $x_2 > x_1 \land x_2 > 0.5$, $x_2$ is max
if $x_2 < x_1 \land x_2 < 0.5$, $x_2$ is min




$x_3$

trivially compare against $x_1$ and $x_2$ to see position and declare as min/mid/max accordingly




A friend gave me this problem and I tried for $n=3$. My strategy was to declare $x_1$ as max if $x_1>2/3$, min if $x_1<1/3$, or middle if $1/3<x_1<2/3$. For $x_2$, if $x_1$ was max, declare $x_2$ as max if $x_2>x_1$ or middle if $x_2<x_1$; if $x_1$ was min, declare $x_2$ as min if $x_2<x_1$ or middle if $x_2>x_1$; if $x_1$ was middle, declare $x_2$ as max if $x_2>x_1$ or min if $x_2<x_1$. For $x_3$, compare it with $x_1$ and $x_2$ and declare position accordingly. This gives a win probability of 1/3, but I was told this is incorrect. I'm not sure how to solve the subcase or the general case

"Optimal" could mean a few distinct things.  For instance, would you like to maximize the expected number of correct answers?  Or perhaps you would like to maximize the chance of getting at least $k$ correct answers, where you choose $k$ beforehand?  The strategies are not necessarily the same... .

@whuber - I interpreted the question to mean we want to maximize the expected number of correct answers

Start, then, with strategies for $n=1$ and $n=2$ before moving on to $n=3.$  You might find it helpful to draw the decision tree for that case.

@whuber - That's what I did. For $n=1$, this is trivial. For $n=2$, if $x_1>0.5$, we declare as max, else min and trivial comparison at $x_2$. Hence my approach for $x_3$. It seems like there is some fundamental flaw with how I'm going about this, but I'm not sure where I'm incorrect.

You haven't exposed the flaw yet because you haven't continued your reasoning through $n=3.$  There are several cases to consider, as the decision tree shows.  For example, suppose $x_1=x_2=0.99:$ what would you guess the rank of $x_3$ should be?  What if $x_1=0.01$ and $x_2=0.99$?  How about $x_1=0.25$ and $x_2=0.75$?

@whuber - I think our interpretation of the question is different. I interpreted it as you guess the position after getting the number. So if $n=3$, $x_3$ case is trivial via direct comparison. I presume you mean to ask what we guess for $x_2$ in the $n=3$ case. If we follow my logic above, $x_2$ is max or middle in case 1, $x_2$ is middle in case 2 and 3 (incorrectly). I'm not sure how to create a semi-formal proof for this though (in order to understand the answer).

Re "$x_3$ case is trivial:" that's not what I wrote.  Once more, I urge you to draw the decision tree and contemplate it.  Think in terms of a recursive solution and be prepared to compute an expected value.

@whuber - I wrote out the decision tree I’m thinking of in the question where it’s more clear. I think EV of this is $1/n$. I’m not quite sure where to go from here if this is incorrect

You have confused me, because earlier you stated you wanted to optimize the expected number of correct answers, but now you assert "we lose [the] game" as soon as just one of the $n$ answers is incorrect.  Which is it??

@whuber - I meant to say we try to optimize our probability of winning (ie. all answers are correct). I thought optimizing probability of winning and number of correct answers would lead to the same strategy given the setup of the game. Apologies for the confusion.

Please, then, provide a clear definition of what you mean by "success" in your post, lest you attract trivial or useless answers that assume it means something else!

@whuber - updated

Thanks!  This version strikes me as potentially difficult.  Clearly you can assure a $1/n!$ chance of winning by guessing without regard to the values you observe, so the issue concerns how much better one can hope to do.

@whuber - Supposedly this is possible in < 10 minutes with minimal pen/paper. I thought there might be a solution using lagrangians, but that’s not “minimal pen and paper”, hence this approach. This approach seems intuitively correct, but I’m not convinced (I can’t come up with even a semi-formal proof)

Because it took us some effort to pin down the interpretation, is it possible the ten minute solution relies on some other interpretation that sounds similar?

The following outlines a further improvement of the strategy derived by @whuber.  It turns out that divisions into subinterval of equal length is not optimal.  Consider the situation at the beginning of the game with $n$ numbers and let $a_0,a_1,a_2,a_n$ with $a_0=0$ and $a_n=1$ denote the yet to be determined locations of the subinterval divisions.  The probability of winning is then given by
\begin{aligned}
W(n) &= \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{j} W(j)W(n-1-j) \int_{a_j}^{a_{j+1}} x^j(1-x)^{n-1-j}\,\mathrm dx.
\end{aligned}
Differentiating with respect to each $a_j$ we obtain
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial W(n)}{\partial a_j} &={n-1 \choose j-1}W(j-1)W(n-j)a_j^{j-1}(1-a_j)^{n-j}\\&-{n-1 \choose j}W(j)W(n-j-1)a_j^{j}(1-a_j)^{n-j-1}
\\&=\frac{(n-1)!a_j^{j-1}(1-a_j)^{n-j-1}}{(j-1)!(n-j-1)!}\left(\frac{W(j-1)W(n-j)(1-a_j)}{n-j}-\frac{W(j)W(n-j-1)a_j}{j}\right)
\end{aligned}
Equating to zero and solving we obtain an optimal value of
$$
a_j=\frac{jW(j-1)W(n-j)}{(n-j)W(j)W(n-j-1)+jW(j-1)W(n-j)}.
$$
For $n=3$, this gives
$$
a_1=\frac3{11}, \quad a_2=\frac{8}{11}
$$
for which $W(3)=377/726\approx 0.5192837$, slightly larger than the winning probability based on equal subdivisions.
For $n$ up to 15, optimal divisions and winning probability (compared to same quantities based on equal subdivisions in grey) are as follows:
library(index0)
strategy <- function(nmax=10, equal=FALSE) {
  p <- function(a1, a2, alpha, beta) {
    (pbeta(a2, alpha, beta)-pbeta(a1, alpha, beta))*beta(alpha, beta)
  }
  w <- index_from_0(c(1,1,.75))
  aa <- list()
  for (n in 3:nmax) {
    j <- 1:(n-1)
    if (equal)
      a <- 1:(n-1)/n
    else
      a <- j*w[j-1]*w[n-j]/((n-j)*w[j]*w[n-j-1] + j*w[j-1]*w[n-j])
    a <- index_from_0(c(0,a,1))
    j <- index_from_0(0:(n-1))
    w[n] <- sum(choose(n - 1,j)*w[j]*w[n - 1 - j]*p(a[j], a[j + 1], j + 1, n - 1 - j + 1))
    aa[[n]] <- a
  }
  list(w=w, a=aa)
}
nmax <- 15
s <- strategy(nmax)
se <- strategy(nmax, TRUE)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(0:nmax, se$w, col="grey",pch=16, log="y", xlab="n", ylab="W(n)")
points(0:nmax, s$w, pch=16)
plot(NA, xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(1,nmax), xlab="Subdivision limits", ylab="n")
for (n in 3:nmax) {
  k <- length(s$a[[n]])
  points(se$a[[n]], rep(n, k), pch=16,col="grey")
  points(s$a[[n]], rep(n, k), pch=16)
}


Created on 2024-04-25 with reprex v2.1.0

+1 Many thanks for finding my error and pursuing it to such an effective result!

Let's attempt a recursive solution.
Notation
Because this can get complicated, suitable notation will help.  To that end,

For $k=0, 1, \ldots, n,$ let $\mathbf x_{(k)}$ be the sequence of the first $k$ values of the $x_i$ along with the endpoints $0$ and $1,$ in ascending order.  Thus this vector has $k+2$ components which I will write $$\mathbf x_{(k)} = (0=x_{k,0},\ x_{k,1},\ \ldots,\ x_{k,k},\ x_{k,k+1}=1).$$

Let $\mathbf r_{(k)}$ represent an ordered sequence of integers $$\mathbf r_{(k)}: 0 = r_{k,0} \lt r_{k,1} \lt r_{k,2}\lt \cdots \lt r_{k,1} \lt r_{k,k+1} = n+1.$$  This represents the ranks we have assigned to $\mathbf x_{(k)},$ where $0$ is the rank of $0$ and $n+1$ is the rank of $1.$


When we observe one of the input numbers $x,$ we will assign a likely final rank (between $1$ and $n,$ with $1$ the smallest and $n$ the largest) to it.  Call this $\operatorname{rank}(x).$
The decision tree for this problem contains nodes of two types, "event" and "decision," that alternate down the tree.  All paths from the root through the tree correspond to sequences $$(x_1, \operatorname{rank}(x_1);\ x_2, \operatorname{rank}(x_2);\ \ldots,\ x_n, \operatorname{rank}(x_n)).$$
The value of each such path indicates whether it is a winning path.  That is, when all the $n$ ranks are the correct ones, the value is $1$ and otherwise the value is $0.$
As usual, let's use capital letters $X_k$ to denote the (uniform, independent) random variables and $x_k$ to denote their realizations.  After observing $k$ realizations, then, we have knowledge of $x_1, \ldots, x_k$ and the ranks we have assigned to them; but we know only the distributions of the unobserved random variables $X_{k+1}, \ldots, X_n.$
Analysis
In these terms, the challenge for any $k= 0, 1, \ldots, n-1$ is to choose $\operatorname{rank}(x_{k+1})$ to maximize the expected value of the path (which equals the chance of winning), given the vectors $\mathbf x_{(k)}$ and $\mathbf r_{(k)}.$  The expectation is taken over the future observations $(X_{k+1}, \ldots, X_n).$  Write $$f(\mathbf x_{(k)}, \mathbf r_{(k)}, n)$$ for this expected value of winning.  The question asks for a strategy to maximize the winning probability $$W(n) = f(\mathbf x_{(0)}, \mathbf r_{(0)}, n) = f((0,1),\ (0,n+1),\ n).$$
The first $k$ values we observe, along with $0$ and $1,$ partition the interval $[0,1)$ into $k+1$ smaller intervals $\mathcal I_{k,j} = [x_{k,j}, x_{k,j+1}),$ $j=0, 1, \ldots, k.$  Explicitly,
$$[0,1] = [0, x_{k,1}) \cup [x_{k,1}, x_{k,2}) \cup \cdots \cup [x_{k,k-1}, x_{k,k}) \cup [x_{k,k}, 1).$$
Let $$\delta_{k,j} = x_{k,j+1} - x_{k,j}$$ be the widths of these intervals.
The ranks we have previously chosen create gaps.  The gap between $r_{k,j}$ and $r_{k,j+1}$ is the number of unassigned ranks between these two ranks, equal to
$$s_{k,j} = r_{k,j+1} - r_{k,j} - 1.$$
For each gap indexed by $j,$ in addition to guessing the ranks correctly, we need exactly $\delta_{k,j}$ of the remaining $n-k$ random variables $X_{k+1}, \ldots, X_n$ to lie in the interval $\mathcal I_{k,j}$ in order to win.  If this does not occur, then no strategy can possibly win.
We can compute that chance.  In terms of multinomial coefficients it equals
$$\binom{n-k}{s_{k,0},\ s_{k,1},\ \ldots,\ s_{k,k}} \prod_{j=0}^k \delta_{k,j}^{s_{k,j}}.\tag{*}$$
The crux of the matter is that, conditional on this event occurring, the problem is reduced (recursively) to finding an optimal strategy to rank the $s_{k,j}$ future (independent uniform) values that will fall into its corresponding gap.  But, up to a change of scale, this is the very same problem, but with only $s_{k,j} \lt n$ variables.
The last step of this analysis is to establish the strategy for the first number observed within any interval.  As is already clear in the question statement, that strategy is to partition that interval into $n$ equal subintervals and assign the rank according to the subinterval.  For instance, with an interval $[x, x+\delta)$ of width $\delta$ starting at $x$ that requires $s=3$ future values between ranks $r+1$ and $r+3,$ we will guess $x_j$ has rank $r+1$ when $0 \le x_j-x\lt\delta/3,$ that it has rank $r+2$ when $\delta/3\le x_j-x\lt 2\delta/3,$ and it has rank $r+3$ when $2\delta/3\le x_j-x\lt \delta.$
It's easy to prove this is optimal (exploit the recursion), so I leave it as an exercise.

Computations
What are the winning chances? It turns out that as $n$ grows, the chance increases astronomically compared to pure guessing (which has a chance of just $1/n!$).
Let's work some out explicitly to illustrate the analysis.  Note at the outset that $W(0)=1$ vacuously.  (This will be useful for the generalization below.)

$n=1.$  We assign rank $1$ to $x_1$ and we're done, winning all the time.  $W(1) = 1.$

$n=2.$  We assign rank $1$ to $x_1$ when $x_1\lt 1/2$ and otherwise guess it will have rank $2.$  We win in the first case when $x_2 \gt x_1$ and in the second case when $x_2 \lt x_1.$  The full expectation is $$W(2) = \int_0^{1/2} \int_{x_1}^1 \mathrm dx_2\,\mathrm dx_1 + \int_{1/2}^1 \int_0^{x_1} \mathrm dx_2\,\mathrm dx_1 = \frac{3}{8} + \frac{3}{8} = \frac{3}{4}.$$

$n=3.$  Now it gets a little interesting.  There are three cases for the first step.

$x_1 \le 1/3.$  The strategy assigns rank $1$ to $x_1.$  The remaining two numbers must lie in the interval $[x_1,1)$ of length $\delta_{1,1} = 1 - x_1$ and that occurs with probability $(1 - x_1)^2$ because those two values are independent.  We have already determined that our chances, conditional on this event, are $3/4.$

$1/3\lt x_1\le 2/3.$  The strategy assigns rank $2$ to $x_1.$  There are two gaps, each of which must be filled with one number.  This occurs with probability $\binom{2}{1,\ 1} (x_1-0)(1-x_1) = 2x_1(1-x_1).$  If this event occurs, we are sure to win (by step 1 above).

$2/3\le x_1 \lt 1).$  This is analyzed as in the first case $x_1\le 1/3$ and has the same value.




Consequently, the chance of winning when $n=3$ is the sum of three integrals corresponding to these events:
$$\begin{aligned}
W(3) &= \binom{2}{0,2}W(2)\int_0^{1/3} (1-x_1)^2\,\mathrm dx_1 \\&\quad + \binom{2}{1,2}W(1)W(1)\int_{1/3}^{2/3} x_1(1-x_1)\,\mathrm dx_1 \\&\quad + \binom{2}{2,0}W(2)\int_{2/3}^1x_1^2\,\mathrm dx_1 \\
&= (1)\left(\frac{3}{4} \right)\left(\frac{19}{81}\right) +  (2)\left(1\right)^2\frac{13}{162} + (1)\left(\frac{3}{4} \right)\left(\frac{19}{81}\right) \\
&= \frac{83}{162} \approx 0.5123457.
\end{aligned}$$
General solution
The pattern becomes clear.  Here is the expected chance of winning, without any further elaboration:
$$\begin{aligned}
W(n) &= \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{j} W(j)W(n-1-j) \int_{j/n}^{(j+1)/n} x^j(1-x)^{n-1-j}\,\mathrm dx
\end{aligned}$$
This comes from taking expectations in formula $(*)$ after observing $x_1$ and guessing its rank according to the optimal strategy.  It employs all known values $W(0), W(1), \ldots, W(n-1)$ recursively.
The integrals are differences of incomplete Beta functions, for which there are efficient accurate algorithms.  This yields a quadratic ($O(n^2)$) algorithm to compute all values $W(0), W(1), \ldots, W(n),$ shown here in an R implementation.
p <- function(a, b) {
  n <- a + b + 1
  (pbeta((a+1)/n, a+1, b+1) - pbeta(a/n, a+1, b+1)) * beta(a+1, b+1)
}
nmax <- 39
w <- c(1, rep(NA, nmax))
for (n in 1:nmax) {
  w[n+1] <- sum(choose(n - 1, 0:(n-1)) * w[1:n] * w[n:1] * p(0:(n-1), (n-1):0))
}
plot(0:nmax, w, log = "y", xlab = "n")


Approximations
The red line (in these log-linear coordinates) graphs an approximate asymptotic function $W(n) \approx \exp(3 - 0.55 n).$  It gets more accurate than shown here as $n$ grows.  Including additive correction terms (for $\log W(n)$) proportional to $1/n,$ $1/n^2,$ and $\log n$ gives an approximation good to better than three decimal places across the full range of values that can be computed in double-precision arithmetic (roughly $n$ from $3$ through $1000$).  That is,
$$\log W(n) \approx 0.3676 - 0.552564 n + 0.2336/n - 0.0489/n^2 + 0.4998\log n,\quad n = 3, 4, \ldots, 1000.$$
The (fully accurate) values continue $W(4) = 55537/165888,$ $W(5) = 11049709/51840000,$ etc., suggesting no simple closed formula is available.

So it seems like my amended strategy was correct for $n=3$? This seems like a mean problem to give verbally. I'm not sure how I was supposed to pin down the EV in 10 minutes...

@olivarb The strategy is different from what you propose.  For $n=3$, if we observe $x_1=0.7$ and thus assign a rank of 3 to $x_1$, the remaining numbers $x_2$ and $x_3$ are iid uniform on $[0,0.7)$ conditional on $x_2$ and $x_3$ both being smaller than $x_1$ such that we have a chance to win the game.  Thus we are faced with a problem of the same type as the initial problem (up to a change of scale) and we should assign a rank of 2 (from the remaining ranks 1 and 2) to $x_2$ if $x_2>0.35$, otherwise a rank of 1.

@whuber +1 But for $n=3$, partitioning the interval $[0,1)$ at $a$ and $1-a$ instead of $1/3$ and $2/3$ and maximising the resulting $W(3)$ with respect to $a$ I get a slightly larger $W(3)=377/726\approx 0.5192837$ for $a=3/11 \approx 0.2727$.  So equal subintervals turns out not be optimal!

@Jarle That's interesting: I might have been mistaken in my assertion about equal divisions--and, in retrospect, that makes sense.  This requires more analysis... .

@whuber I found a nice recursion for the optimal divisions and added a second answer.

This is not an answer but only considers a general strategy coinciding with that of the OP that turns out to be suboptimal.
After having observed the first $k$ random variables out of all $n$ variables $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$, let $r_{k,k}$ denote the current rank of $x_k$ among $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_k$.  Conditional on $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_k$, the final rank $r_k$ of $x_k$ among $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$ is clearly distributed as
$$
r_k \sim r_{k,k} + \operatorname{bin}(n-k,x_k) \tag{1}
$$
since each of the remaining $n-k$ variables $x_{k+1},x_{k+2},\dots, x_n$ will be smaller than $x_k$ independently and with probability $x_k$ and each of these events increases the final rank of $x_k$ by one.
A possible strategy is to assign as rank $a_k$ to $x_k$ the mode of the conditional probability mass function of the final rank $r_k$ given by
$$
a_k=r_{k,k}+\lfloor (n-k + 1)x_k\rfloor.
$$
For $n=3$ this coincides with the strategy of the OP.
While this choice of $a_k$ makes no regard to the later choices for $a_{k+1},\dots a_n$, it follows from linearity of expectation, that it is optimal in terms of maximising the expected number of correct rankings.  However, as the aim of the game is to maximise the probability that all assigned  ranks are correct ($a_k=r_k$ for $k=1,2,\dots,n$), it is not, as shown by the following counter example.
Suppose $n=3$ and $x_1=0.6$. The above strategy then leads to $a_1=2$.   If then observe $x_2=0.55$, then $r_{2,2}=1$ and the most likely final rank of $x_2$ is $r_2=2$ since $P(x_3 < x_2)=0.55$.  So by the above strategy we should choose $a_2=2$.  But then we have $a_1=a_2=2$ and we loose the game with probability one.  On the other hand, if we instead choose $a_2=1$ we still have a chance of get all ranks correct with probability $P(x_3>x_1)=1-x_1=0.4$.
